# join multiple mongo DB collection with array of object field

Tags: mongodb

I have two mongo DB collection named posts and users.The common field between them is email.The posts collection have **array of objects of comments**.The comments have array of **commentLikes** and **commentReplys**.The commentReplys have array of object of **replyLikes**.I want the details of user who had commented,liked comment,reply and liked the reply.

The users collection:

```
 {
        "_id": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
        "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
        "name": "Deepa Shrestha",
        "phone": 9819339011,
        "profile": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
        "dob": "2001-03-26T08:00:00.000Z",
        "join_at": "2022-08-23T14:27:43.249Z",
        "password": "Devraj 123@",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6304e43b31ef2e7a4dec9251",
        "email": "devrajstha88@gmail.com",
        "name": "Devraj Shrestha",
        "phone": 9819339011,
        "profile": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
        "dob": "2001-03-26T08:00:00.000Z",
        "join_at": "2022-08-23T14:27:43.249Z",
        "password": "Devraj 123@",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "6304e44431ef2e7a4dec9254",
        "email": "dstha221@gmail.com",
        "name": "Radha Shrestha",
        "phone": 9819339011,
        "profile": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
        "dob": "2001-03-26T08:00:00.000Z",
        "join_at": "2022-08-23T14:27:43.249Z",
        "password": "Devraj 123@",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Posts collection:

```
{
        "_id": "630ac8bc7e49b4f426aedc5d",
        "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
        "posts": [
            {
                "postType": "image",
                "post": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
                "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e903"
            },
            {
                "postType": "image",
                "post": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
                "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e904"
            }
        ],
        "postAt": "2022-08-28T01:38:47.606Z",
        "status": "testing status",
        "comments": [
            {
                "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                "commentText": "Testing comment",
                "isNotified": true,
                "commentAt": "2022-08-23T14:41:55.646Z",
                "commentReplys": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "email": "dstha221@gmail.com",
                        "replyText": "Testing comment",
                        "isNotified": true,
                        "replyAt": "2022-08-23T14:41:55.646Z",
                        "replyLikes": [
                            {
                                "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                                "isNotified": true,
                                "email": "dstha221@gmail.com",
                                "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e907"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e906"
                    },
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                        "replyText": "reply text testing",
                        "isNotified": true,
                        "replyAt": "2022-08-23T15:57:51.259Z",
                        "replyLikes": [
                            {
                                "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                                "isNotified": true,
                                "email": "dstha221@gmail.com",
                                "_id": "6308e1d1acaea2a7ec6dc7fa"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "6304f90191c32e0deac663b8"
                    }
                ],
                "commentLikes": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
                        "isNotified": true,
                        "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                        "_id": "630ac8bc7e49b4f426aedc65"
                    }
                ],
                "commentId": "bc174de0-22f1-11ed-9c5d-23d89a83ff32",
                "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e905"
            },
            {
                "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                "commentText": "Testing comment",
                "isNotified": true,
                "commentAt": "2022-08-23T15:02:11.123Z",
                "commentReplys": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                        "replyText": "reply text testing",
                        "isNotified": true,
                        "replyAt": "2022-08-23T15:57:51.259Z",
                        "replyLikes": [
                            {
                                "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                                "isNotified": true,
                                "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                                "_id": "6308e1d1acaea2a7ec6dc7fd"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "6304f90191c32e0deac663b8"
                    }
                ],
                "commentLikes": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "isNotified": true,
                        "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                        "_id": "6308e1d1acaea2a7ec6dc7fe"
                    }
                ],
                "commentId": "90928740-22f4-11ed-b912-e99836187b6d",
                "_id": "6304ec67825b5926f0f074cf"
            },
            {
                "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                "commentText": "Testing comment",
                "isNotified": true,
                "commentAt": "2022-08-23T15:02:11.123Z",
                "commentReplys": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                        "replyText": "reply text testing",
                        "isNotified": true,
                        "replyAt": "2022-08-23T15:57:51.259Z",
                        "replyLikes": [
                            {
                                "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                                "isNotified": true,
                                "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                                "_id": "630ac8bc7e49b4f426aedc6c"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "6304f90191c32e0deac663b8"
                    }
                ],
                "commentLikes": [
                    {
                        "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                        "isNotified": true,
                        "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                        "_id": "6308e1d1acaea2a7ec6dc801"
                    }
                ],
                "commentId": "90928740-22f4-11ed-b912-e99836187b6d",
                "_id": "6304ec81825b5926f0f074d1"
            }
        ],
        "likes": [
            {
                "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
                "isNotified": true,
                "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                "_id": "63052dc7a1728d463769681b"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0,
    }
```

The desired output:

```
{
    "_id": "630ac8bc7e49b4f426aedc5d",
    "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
    "posts": [
        {
            "postType": "image",
            "post": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
            "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e903"
        },
        {
            "postType": "image",
            "post": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
            "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e904"
        }
    ],
    "postAt": "2022-08-28T01:38:47.606Z",
    "status": "testing status",
    "comments": [
        {
            "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
            "commentText": "Testing comment",
            "isNotified": true,
            "commentAt": "2022-08-23T14:41:55.646Z",
            "commentUser":{
                "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                "name": "Deepa Shrestha",
                "profile": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg"
            },
            "commentReplys": [
                {
                    "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                    "email": "dstha221@gmail.com",
                    "replyText": "Testing comment",
                    "isNotified": true,
                    "replyAt": "2022-08-23T14:41:55.646Z",
                    "commentReplyUser":{
                        "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                "name": "Deepa Shrestha",
                "profile": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg"
                    },
                    "replyLikes": [
                        {
                            "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                            "isNotified": true,
                            "email": "dstha221@gmail.com",
                            "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e907",
                            "replyLikeUser":{
                                "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                        "name": "Deepa Shrestha",
                        "profile": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e906"
                },
                {
                    "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                    "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                    "replyText": "reply text testing",
                    "isNotified": true,
                    "replyAt": "2022-08-23T15:57:51.259Z",
                    "replyLikes": [
                        {
                            "userId": "6304e02d481e08d44e618d41",
                            "isNotified": true,
                            "email": "dstha221@gmail.com",
                            "_id": "6308e1d1acaea2a7ec6dc7fa",
                            "replyLikeUser":{
                                "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                        "name": "Deepa Shrestha",
                        "profile": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "6304f90191c32e0deac663b8"
                }
            ],
            "commentLikes": [
                {
                    "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
                    "isNotified": true,
                    "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                    "_id": "630ac8bc7e49b4f426aedc65",
                    "commentLikeUser":{
                        "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
                "name": "Deepa Shrestha",
                "profile": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "commentId": "bc174de0-22f1-11ed-9c5d-23d89a83ff32",
            "_id": "6304e73ecdc5d350cc33e905"
        }
    ],
    "likes": [
        {
            "userId": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
            "isNotified": true,
            "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
            "_id": "63052dc7a1728d463769681b",
            "likedUser":{
                    "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
            "name": "Deepa Shrestha",
            "profile": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg"
                
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
    
}
```

The api code:

```
router.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  postModel.aggregate([
    { $lookup:
      {
         from: "users",
         localField: "email",
         foreignField: "email",
         as: "user"
      },
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "comments.$[].email",
        foreignField: "email",
        as:"commentUser"
      },
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "comments.commentReplys.$[].email",
          foreignField: "email",
          as:"replyUser"
        }, 
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "comments.commentLikes.[].email",
          foreignField: "email",
          as:"replyLikeUser"
        }, 
      
  }
  ]).exec(function(err, doc) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(doc)
  
  });
})
```

I didnot get the expected result.How to get and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just have 2 syntax errors in your code:

1. each `$lookup` should be a separate pipeline stage.
2. `$lookup` already supports array element access, the `$[]` array modifier is an update operator and cannot be used in a lookup but as mentioned there is no need to use it, you can just write `comments.commentReplys.email` using Mongo's dot notation.

Here is the full fixed pipeline:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "email",
      foreignField: "email",
      as: "user"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "comments.email",
      foreignField: "email",
      as: "commentUser"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "comments.commentReplys.email",
      foreignField: "email",
      as: "replyUser"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "comments.commentLikes.email",
      foreignField: "email",
      as: "replyLikeUser"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-EmgBjTEFs-)

---

However this pipeline is very inefficient, `$lookup` is a very expensive stage from a performance perspective - and in this case instead of duplicating it and executing 4 unique lookups you could just merge it into 1 here is a sample of how to do it:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: {
        email: "$email",
        commentEmails: "$comments.email",
        replyComments: "$comments.commentReplys.email",
        likedComments: "$comments.commentLikes.email"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$email",
                {
                  "$concatArrays": [
                    [
                      "$$email"
                    ],
                    "$$commentEmails",
                    "$$replyComments",
                    "$$likedComments",
                    
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        
      ],
      as: "matches"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yFUZKML3LQD)

Last thing I'll mention is that you are using emails, but emails could usually be changed, it's much more stable to use the `_id` of the user - which you are already saving on the posts it seems.

Comment: the desired output is still not getting...

Comment: It gives only one object of user though the user have liked or comment two or more times...

Comment: It was just to show how to execute a proper lookup, you will always need to `$map` over the input and match each user

Comment: can you  map once ...

Comment: Sure, [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OayY8fwzXFO) is an example for "likedUser"

Comment: but it is giving only one user...

Comment: only 1 user in the sample data you provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247624/discussion-between-jeevan-shrestha-and-tom-slabbaert).

Comment: It is  just sample,the  user is different

Comment: You can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SmPni4wT6qG) if i add another used to the like array it works.